# Do props update when called inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a function that modifies a registry in the database and then updates the recently modified registry in the frontend, but I'm having issues getting the updated value from received props because it seems the function retains the original value of props even after updating.

```
const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = useState({});

const modifyOrder = async (parameters) => {
await props.modify(parameters); //This function modifies and then refreshes the data
console.log(props.client.orderList); //This value doesn't update
let refreshedValue = props.client.orderList.filter(o => o.id === selectedOrder.id)[0];
clickOrder(refreshedValue); //This function calls setSelectedOrder
}

console.log(props.client.orderList); //This value updates correctly, and it happens before the console.log in the function
return(<html code....>)
```

Edit: corrected a typo, added some pseudocode for clarity

Comment: `async props.modify(parameters);` should be `await props.modify(parameters);`

Comment: you are right, it was a typo in the question, in my code I have it with "await"